# GenServer in elixir delaying task

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to show a post to the first friend of a person first and other's after making a delay of 1 min. For that I am using GenServer.

The problem is that the first friend as well as the other friends are getting the post after 1 min.

Here is my code of GenServer:

```
defmodule Phoenix.SchedulePost do
  use GenServer
  
  def start_link(state) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, state)
  end
  
  def init(state) do
    schedule_post(state)
    {:ok, state}
  end
  
  # handling looby
  def handle_info(:postSchedule, state) do
    #sending posts to others
    {:noreply, state}
  end
  
  # scheduling a task
  defp schedule_post(state) do
    IO.puts "scheduling the task"
    Process.send_after(self(), :postSchedule, 60*1000)
  end
end
```

I am starting a GenServer process for each post request and sending it to the first friend. Here is the code:

```
def handle_in("post:toFrstFrnd", %{"friendId"=>friendId,"body" => body}, socket) do
  newSocket = PhoenixWeb.SocketBucket.get_socket(friendId)
  if  newSocket != nil do
    push newSocket, "post:toFrstFrnd", %{"friendId": friendId,"body": body}
  end
  Phoenix.SchedulePost.start_link(postId)
  {:noreply, socket}
end
```

Help me out, thank you in advance.

Comment: Where's the code that sends the message to the first friend?

Comment: I am updating the above post

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, I had updated.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I know it's a rather old question, but maybe someone else has a similar problem and ends up here.

I think you want to trigger an action initially and then another action a minute later. The problem with your code is that you call the `schedule_post` method in your `init` method and it does nothing for a minute. After one minute you send a message to the process itself, whereupon `handle_info` method takes over. But now it is already much too late for the initial action.

Here is an example how you could do it:

```
defmodule Phoenix.SchedulePost do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(state \\ []) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, state)
  end

  def init(state) do
    send(self(), :first_action)
    {:ok, state}
  end

  def handle_info(:first_action, state) do
    IO.puts("Called immediately")
    # Do something here...

    Process.send_after(self(), :second_action, 60 * 1000)
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def handle_info(:second_action, state) do
    IO.puts "Called after 1 min"
    # Do something here...

    {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```

But keep in mind that the process will continue to live even after the second action is done. It will not terminate automatically, you have to take care of that.